# Draw '8' in css

Tags: css, draw, css-shapes

```css
.seven_number {
    position: absolute;
    right: 147px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 14px;
}

.seven_number:after {
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    top: 0px;
    left: -2px;
}

.seven_number:before {
    content: "";
    height: 27px;
    width: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
```

```html
<div class="seven_number"></div>
```

This code is to draw a 7 with css like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVBXi.png

Can anyone help me draw an 8 like that please?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Usually we expect people to provide some examples of what they tried before asking for help, so we can help you troubleshoot and suggest improvements.
Would you mind editing your question to add some examples of things you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this style as example:

```css
.eight_number {
    position: absolute;
    right: 187px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 14px;
}

.eight_number:after {
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:4px solid #c6c6c6; 
}
.eight_number:before {
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:-2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:4px solid #c6c6c6; 
}
```

```html
<div class="eight_number"></div>
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/egv64dk7/16/#&togetherjs=ivslT1OqpI